# Запустить программу в виде docker-контейнера с внешними каталогами

Tags: docker

У меня есть небольшой код, который заменяет текст в файлах указанного каталога.
В качестве аргументов командной строки на вход даются путь в каталогу, искомый текст и замещающий текст.

Программа в результате своей работы:
а) заменяет текст в файлах каталога.
б) создает лог-файл в своем каталоге.

Вопрос - как в dockerfile привязать внешние папки к контейнеру так чтобы:
а) при выполнении кода, запущенного в контейнере, в папке хоста появился лог-файл
б) при запуске контейнера можно было б указать любую папку хоста?
В данный момент контейнер, собранный с помощью dockerfile позволяет только запустить код

Comment: dockerfile привязать внешние папки к контейнеру нельзя, это можно сделать только при создании контейнера.

Comment: хорошо. как это сделать? :c

Comment: Есть поражающий своей нетривиальностью вариант — прочитать документацию по docker run.

Comment: Alexey, что-то конкретное можете подсказать?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/